# Taking is JSON data in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

So I have AFNetworking working just fine, I can get json data and format it in a tableview as long as the JSON file as an Array called "results."

Example:

```
{
     "results": [
     {
  "title": "title",
  "subtitle": "subtitle",
  "description": "",
  "image": ""
     }
   ]
}
```

My code in xcode to parse this with AFNetworking is:

```
-(void)makeGiftRequests
{   
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://SOMEURL.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    self.giftsArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];

    NSLog(@"The Array: %@",self.giftsArray);

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

}];

[operation start];
}
```

But I cant for the life of me figure out how to parse it if the json file looks as follows:

```
[
   {
     "title": "",
     "subtitle:""
   }
]
```

I'm sure its horribly simple but I'm no pro. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....
`self. giftsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseobject];`

Answer (score 0):

The responseObject which you get from `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is of type `id` means it can be anything so you can typeCast it to NSDictionary or NSArray depending on the output you expect.

```
 self.giftsArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
```